# DateTime.TryParse -> "Ghost ticks"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

i've the following unit test, which fails on the machine of one of our developers (He get some ticks in the result variable, while the datetime variable is at zero ticks), but runs well on every other machine.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DateTimeStringDateTimeMinCurrentCultureToNullableDateTimeSuccessTest()
    {
        var dateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        string value = dateTime.ToString();
        var result = value.ToNullableDateTime();
        Assert.AreEqual(dateTime, result);
    }
```

Here's the used extension method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string to a nullable DateTime. If the string is a invalid dateTime returns null.
    /// Uses the current culture.
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(this string s)
    {
        //Don't use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to override user changes of the cultureinfo.
        return s.ToNullableDateTime(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string to a nullable DateTime. If the string is a invalid dateTime returns null.
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(this string s, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return null;
        DateTime i;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(s, cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out i)) return i;
        return null;
    }
```

I think this might be related to some windows date time settings he uses. In theory the `ToNullableDateTime(string)` should create a new culture info, which is user machine neutral. `GetCultureInfo` should call `new CultureInfo(name, false)`. The only thing I could come up with, is that there's a cached culture info, which contains some kind of user machine related modified datetime in the `s_NameCachedCultures` which is checked in the `GetCultureInfoHelper` (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,5fe58d4ecbba7689).

I know, that the `CreateSpecificCulture` method can return a user modified datetime, if you call it with the same culture than the windows machine. But I always thought, the `GetDateTime` would return a unmodified datetime in any case.

So there are two questions:

- Could it be possible, that a modified `CultureInfo` be stored in the internal cache?
- If so, is the only way to get a unmodified `CultureInfo` by manually calling `new CultrueInfo("xy", false)`?

Comment: Why did you choose to use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` in the short overload of the extension method? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yck8b540.aspx) says a reason to prefer it over the plain instance constructor (`new CultureInfo(...)`) is speed because of caching.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what `s` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` are on the machine that fails the test, and also on a machine where the test passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overseen a little detail. The problem wasn't related to the GetCultureInfo returning a modified datetime, the problem already startet with the `dateTime.ToString();` which uses the `Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo` (which equals to the windows culture, which can be modified). The developers machine translates the `DateTime(1, 1, 1)` to `01.01.01 00:00:00`. On any other machine the output is `01.01.0001 00:00:00`. So an abbreviated version of the year is used, which seems to be interpreted as the "year 1 of the current century" in the `TryParse` method (quick sidenode: So it's not possible for users older than 100 years to tell their birthdate with the abbreviated year version). 
It's actually an interesting behaviour..

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var year = 1900 + i;
            DateTime date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString("yy"), "yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", year, parsedDate.ToString("yyyy"));
        }
```

leads to:

```
[...]
1928: 2028
1929: 2029
1930: 1930
1931: 1931
[...]
```

So, the abbreviated birth date for anyone older 86 would lead to a date in the feature.. but this moves away from the questions context ..

I think there's no real solution the actual problem (beside telling developers to not use local CultureInfos outside of UI strings and never use abbreviated dates for inputs).

We don't have such problems in our code itself, because we use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for all internal stuff. I just think about the unit test .. I think the test itself is correct. It shows, that the function actually doesn't work correct with abbreviated dates. I will change the behaviour of the `ToNullableDateTime()` to throw an exception, if a datetime string with a abbreviated year is recognized.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

> string value = dateTime.ToString();

this will use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.  You then try and parse this string using...

> CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

So you are specifically using a culture to parse the string that is different to the one you've created the string with.  Of course there will be instances where this doesn't pass.

I'd suggest the issue is on most peoples machines

```
Assert.AreEqual(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));
```

would pass but on the machine in question it doesn't and neither do your strings.

I'd suggest you probably want to use [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx). So...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DateTimeStringDateTimeMinCurrentCultureToNullableDateTimeSuccessTest()
    {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        string value = dateTime.ToStringInvariant();
        var result = value.ToNullableDateTime();
        Assert.AreEqual(dateTime, result);
    }


    public static string ToStringInvariant(this DateTime? date)
    {
        if (date.HasValue)
            return date.Value.ToStringInvariant();

        return null;
    }

    public static string ToStringInvariant(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string to a nullable DateTime. If the string is a invalid dateTime returns null.
    /// Uses the current culture.
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(this string s)
    {
        //Don't use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to override user changes of the cultureinfo.
        return s.ToNullableDateTime(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a string to a nullable DateTime. If the string is a invalid dateTime returns null.
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime? ToNullableDateTime(this string s, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return null;
        DateTime i;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(s, cultureInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out i)) return i;
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, most probably the `CultureInfo` is in a cache. This would be very easy to check in a unit test (`AreSame`).

Instead of `DateTime(1, 1, 1)` use `DateTime(1, 2, 3)` and check the ghost ticks. Are they found in the string somewhere? Did you try the same culture (hard-coded culture name) on two machines which had different results?

Also check if the difference is the offset to UTC in your culture.

You probably can use `TryParseExact`.